# TextBlob not returning the correct number of instances of string in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, textblob

For a project for my lab, I'm analyzing Twitter data. The tweets we've captured all have the word 'sex' in them, that's the keyword we filtered the TwitterStreamer to capture based on.

I converted the CSV where all of the tweet data (json metatags) is housed into a pandas DB and saved the 'text' column to isolate the tweet text.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import csv
    df = pd.read_csv('tweets_hiv.csv')
    saved_column4 = df.text
    print saved_column4
```

Out comes the correct output:

```
    0                                Some example tweet text
    1                 Oh hey look more tweet text @things I hate #stuff
    ...a bunch more lines
    Name: text, Length: 8540, dtype: object
```

But, when I try this

```
    from textblob import TextBlob
    tweetstr = str(saved_column4)
    tweets = TextBlob(tweetstr).upper()
    print tweets.words.count('sex', case_sensitive=False)
```

My output is `22`.

There should be AT LEAST as many incidences of the word 'sex' as there are lines in the CSV, and likely more. I can't figure out what's happening here. Is TextBlob not configuring right around a dtype:object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this is methodically correct insofar as language processing, but using `join` will give you the count you need.

```
import pandas as pd
from textblob import TextBlob

tweets = pd.Series('sex {}'.format(x) for x in range(1000))
tweetstr = " ".join(tweets.tolist())
tweetsb = TextBlob(tweetstr).upper()
print tweetsb.words.count('sex', case_sensitive=False)
# 1000
```

---

If you just need the count without necessarily using `TextBlob`, then just do:

```
import pandas as pd

tweets = pd.Series('sex {}'.format(x) for x in range(1000))
sex_tweets = tweets.str.contains('sex', case=False)
print sex_tweets.sum()
# 1000
```

---

You can get a `TypeError` in the first snippet if one of your elements is not of type `string`. This is more of `join` issue. A simple test can be done using the following snippet:

```
# tweets = pd.Series('sex {}'.format(x) for x in range(1000))
tweets = pd.Series(x for x in range(1000))
tweetstr = " ".join(tweets.tolist())
```

Which gives the following result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    tweetstr = " ".join(tweets.tolist())
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, numpy.int64 found
```

A simple workaround is to convert `x` in the list comprehension into a `string` before using `join`, like so:

```
tweets = pd.Series(str(x) for x in range(1000))
```

Or you can be more explicit and create a list first, map the `str` function to it, and then use `join`.

```
tweetlist = tweets.tolist()
tweetstr = map(str, tweetlist)
tweetstr = " ".join(tweetstr)
```

Comment: When I try to join the list, I get this error, "TypeError: sequence item 368: expected string, float found". I assume that's because that tweet contains a URL and some backslashes. How do I get around that and convert my Series into a string? When I use the 2nd suggested code and skip the textblob, it's still functioning on the truncated str version.

Comment: When that error occurs, that means that the 369th item in your list is not a string-type element but a float. I'll edit in a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The CSV conversion is not the problem!  When you use `str()` on a column of a `DataFrame` (that is, a `Series`), it makes a "print-friendly" output of the Series, which means cutting out the majority of the data, and just displaying the first few and the last few.  Here is a transcript of an IPython session that will probably illustrate the issue better:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: blah = pd.Series('tweet %d' % n for n in range(1000))

In [3]: blah
Out[3]: 
0        tweet 0
1        tweet 1
...  (output continues from 1 to 29)
29       tweet 29
       ... (OUTPUT SKIPS HERE)
970    tweet 970
... (output continues from 970 to 998)
998    tweet 998
999    tweet 999
dtype: object

In [4]: blahstr = str(blah)

In [5]: blahstr.count('tweet')
Out[5]: 60
```

So, since the output of the `str()` operation cuts off my data (and might even truncate column values, If I had used longer strings), I don't get 1000, I get 60.

If you want to do it your way (combine everything *back* into a single string and work with it that way), there's no point in using a library like Pandas.  Pandas gives you better ways:

### Working With a Series of Strings

Pandas has tools for working with a `Series` that contains strings.  Here is a [tutorial-like page about it](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html), and here is the full [string handling API documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling).  In particular, for finding the number of uses of the word "sex", you could do something like this (assuming `df` is a `DataFrame`, and `text` is the column containing the tweets):

```
import re
counts = df['text'].str.count('sex', re.IGNORECASE)
```

`counts` should be a `Series` containing the number of occurrences of "sex" in each tweet.  `counts.sum()` would give you the total number of usages, which should hopefully be more than 1000.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Any ideas how to combine the tweet column in a way that preserves everything?

Comment: See my edited answer, it has a new section describing how you can do string operations on the string column without "combining" everything back into a single string.